# How to recover a graph without instructions to produce it?

Tags: graphics

I have an output graph on a saved notebook that I cannot reproduce with my data (I messed up the instructions).

Can I take that graph, insert it in a new notebook and modify it? (I'm thinking about axes, labels, fonts, etc.)

Comment: short answer: yes

Comment: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kXNRa.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2)[`Read the FAQs`] 
(http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean "graph" as in "plot of a function", then assign your graph to a variable and then extract/modify its properties. Imagine you have just this:

[image]

Then this is an example of "extract/modify its properties":

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, Thick, pl[[1, 3, 2]]}], Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}, AspectRatio -> .6]
```

[image]

If on other hand you have "graph" as a network, then there are many options to go around, because `Graph` returns an object where all information about `Graph` is preserved. This is one way to do it:

[image]

```
Show[AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[gr], 
  AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexCoordinates], GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"], 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: for clarity, once youve closed the nodebook and quit the kernel, to get the plot back as an object you can modify you need to copy the graphic (right click/copy) and past into an input cell, setting equal to a variable.

Comment: Just a note: such a solution has been possible only since the day (with Version 6??) that graphics output ceased being merely a side-effect of code and became instead an actual Mathematica object capable of being operated upon like any other object.

Comment: Yup, I didnt know this till looking at this question.. I guess it would be worthwhile to read those release notes!!